# Set color of a shape drawable used as a TextView background in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am using a shape defined as a drawable as background for a TextView. This allows me to add rounded corners and other other effects.
The shape is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

and I am using it like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/project"
    style="@style/textView"
    android:background="@drawable/project_textview_background"
/>
```

Now, I need to change the color of that TextView programmatically depending on some conditions. I have not been able to do that.

- I tried to do setBackgroundColor but that seems to overwrite the background I previously defined so it doesn't show the rounded corners anymore.
- I looked at a bunch of other API methods but got nowhere

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post a bit of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was actually to set the shape and color in code instead of using a drawable resource. 
I used [PaintDrawable(int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/PaintDrawable.html) which allows me to define whatever background color I want. Then I used the setCornerRadoii(float[]) to define the rounded corners and finally I assigned the PaintDrawable object to my textView background. Worked like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

You could make other shapes that still has that corner attribute you already defined. 
The way to fill the cell with bgcolor is written in next web page.(solid)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

And if the conditions you mentioned depend on focus or press, you'd better to make selector instead of shape. Search with keyword "ColorStateList" in android reference. I want to leave the address, but I can't due to my reputation;;;

Comment: I know it's a little strange but I have 12 different colors. I wanted to avoid creating 12 different shapes. I will take another look at the ColorStateList. Thanks

Comment: I do not rely on View states (enabled, selected, etc...) so I cannot use the ColorStateList. Unless there is a way to define custom states but I don't know how

Comment: So how about creating custom widget derived textview?

Comment: That sounds complicated just to change the background color of a textview but I will explore that option. Thanks